# Node.js listing objects in views

Tags: node.js, render

How do I list my posts in node.js?

**server.js**

```
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', hbs.__express);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM wp_posts', function(err, rows, fields) {
        res.render('index', {posts: rows});
    });

});
```

**client, index.html:**

```
{{#each post in posts}}
    {{post.title}}
{{/each}}
```

How does this work, please help guys. I searched but everyone told this with jade or hbs. I want to use standart html render.

Comment: what exactly isn't working?

Comment: @Vadim, posts are not listing in views.

Comment: Are you getting any error in particular? "not working" isn't a useful description. What do you get instead of posts? Also what do you mean `standard html render`? What you've shown us is Handlebars, not standard HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your template is wrong. Try:

```
{{#each posts}}
    {{title}}
{{/each}}
```